# Should I add another Group By Statement when I receive the error "column cannot be resolved"?

Tags: sql, syntax-error, presto, case-statement, trino

My query was running fine, but after a adding a case statement I received an error on some of the column.

QUERY with the case statement that I am receiving an error on:

```
select 
date_,
afs,
sum(price) as Customer_price,
sum(cost) as store_cost,
pos_vd,
product

CASE 
 WHEN f.afs='C' and  f.product  in ('Blue','Pink','Yellow') 
THEN 'Special'
ELSE 'PRODUCT GROUP NOT MAPPED' END as ProductGroup

from pie.crust f 
where 
date_ >= 201801 and 
pos_vd = 'Stop'


Group By 
date_,
afs,
pos_vd,
product,

CASE 
  WHEN f.afs='C' and  f.product  in ('Blue','Pink','Yellow') 
THEN 'Special'
ELSE 'PRODUCT GROUP NOT MAPPED' END
```

Below are the fields I am receiving an error on. When I remove the fields the query works with the case statement, but I need the field in my data pull. I tried adding the case statement under Group By and it didn't work. I keep receiving the error like "Column 'price' cannot be received":

```
sum(price),
sum(cost)
```

Comment: Left justified SQL is just so hard to read, and to write.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! [mcve]

Comment: Hello, I simplified the query. The fields listed in the second part is what is causing the error.

Comment: You are missing a comma before the `CASE`.  I'm voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You can not give alias in the `group by`. Remove the aliases from `group by` and also I don't think aggregate functions are required in the `group by`.

You should remove the following aggregate functions.

```
sum(cnt) as CNT,
sum(amt) as AMT,
sum(price) as Customer_price,
sum(cost) as store_cost,
```

And you can use `case..when` in `group by` without alias.

```
CASE 
        WHEN f.afs='C' and  f.product  in ('Blue','Pink','Yellow') 
THEN 'Special'
ELSE 'PRODUCT GROUP NOT MAPPED' END -- no alias
```

Comment: Sorry I did not clean up the query in my question, but when I was running my actual query I did not have alias in the group by or the aggregate functions under Group By. Also when I included the case statement under Group By I removed the alias. I stilled received the error,

Comment: You must show the query which is throwing an error

Comment: I refined the question to show the query I am receiving an error on.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I solved this problem.

The table was originally created in HUE, so when I was trying to add the case statement in Presto and pull the aggregate function it wouldn't work. I went back to the original table in Hive and added the case statement there. Now when I pull the data from Presto everything is working.